# Activity stream for SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, web-part, activity-feed

Are there any web parts for SharePoint 2007 offering an activity streaming facility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I know what you mean but the **Colleague Tracker** Web Part shows information about certain activities.

[image: Colleague Tracker Web Part]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do custom activites, I've written a blog article about how to do this in SP 2007.

http://www.thelineberrys.com/default-category/adding-custom-activities-for-the-colleague-tracker-in-sp-2007-2.html